# How to decode a binary file containing an array of floats?

Tags: python, arrays, decoding, binary-data

> encoded_floats_hex = [     "35F1AC3D", "610BB63D", "8C25BF3D", "B73FC83D", "E259D13D",      "0E74DA3D",     "B5AB5C00", "D3972400", "6D9B2400", "B5A82400", "4A75E003", "ED20E403",     "11D7F803", "0F7EEF03", "BAD41500", "56341200", "6B5C1200", "BE753200",     "E94B3E00", "EA4D3600", "BE372E00", "6BDC1500", "56FC1200", "B9D41300",     "E9CC7200", "D6347E00", "BB547600", "6E7C6E00", "5A541600", "B94B1200",     "EECD1300", "DBD73200", "B7FD3D00", "6ADC3600", "59342E00", "B64C1600",     "EA541200", "DF741200", "9281F000", "FC39F600", "5B0EFC00", "3254F600",     "FB7B0B00", "EDEE0E00", "D71D0900", "3D2A1900", "2C261900", "573A1B00",     "7D2A1700", "6B1E0B00", "55EA0E00", "3C660900", "2BE63900", "D56B3900",     "FF1E3B00", "D52D3700", "D43A0B00", "3F260F00", "552A0900", "6B1A1900",     "7D6E1900", "54FA1A00", "2C661700", "3DE60B00", "D71B0F00", "ED2E0900",     "FB3D7900", "D42A7900", "2D267900", "3B1A7700", "55EA0B00", "6F7E0F00",     "74EA0A00", "55661900", "2F261900", "352A1900", "DB3E1700", "EC2D0B00",     "F51A0F00", "DBE70A00", "2D6A3900", "37FA3900", "5C6E3900", "6C1A3700",     "77260B00", "5D260F00", "2B3A0B00", "352E1900", "DC1D1900", "EB6A1900",     "F5E71600", "DF7A0B00", "35EA0F00", "341E0B00" ]

this array contain hex values for float 4 bytes on little endian, the first 6 values can be decoded but after those, the decoded floats are unexpected:

```
# Convert the hex strings to bytes
encoded_bytes = [bytes.fromhex(x) for x in encoded_hex]
# convert the each byte array into a float
float_values = [struct.unpack('f', x)[0] for x in encoded_bytes]
float_values 

[0.08444444090127945,
 0.08888889104127884,
 0.09333333373069763,
 0.09777777642011642,
 0.10222221910953522,
 0.1066666692495346,
 8.510462523131517e-39,
 3.360542129100596e-39,
 3.361834126284704e-39,
 3.366598541063408e-39,
 1.3192464977331103e-36,...]
```

**It seems to be encoded by some custom delta encoding.**

On the other hand, all the array are made of **numbers between 0 and 1, which don't need exponential annotation, and increasing from 0.0 to 1.0 except for last values**.

Any idea of how to decode it?

I tried several decodings, but none of the are giving the expected results.

Comment: seems to be IEEE-754 if you reverse the hex string https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8766229 (verified here https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html by inputting "3dacf135" as the hexadecimal representation)

Comment: What value do you expect from "B5AB5C00"?

Comment: IEEE-754 float32 little-endian should end in byte 3D, 3E, or 3F for the values .1 to .9.  Check that your data was written correctly since you've indicated they should increase from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: Data is correct, but encoded from 7 element. 

“B5AB5C00” it needs to be decoded and data around can affect since it is using delta encoding probably. Expected values are from 0.0 to 1.0 and without exponential annotations.

Answer (score 1):

> hex values for float 4 bytes on little endian

Let's focus on this part.

The reading of file itself is trivial so we assume it's already read into memory as a list of such hex string.

Since your order is little endian, the byte can be decoded from the string by reversing the bytes.fromhex result:

```
bytes.fromhex("35F1AC3D")[::-1]
```

Then all we need to do is to unpack the bytes to target format data (e.g., float here since your string has only 4 bytes):

```
float_out = struct.unpack('>f', bytes.fromhex("35F1AC3D")[::-1])[0]
```

Alternatively, simply use the '<f' format (little-endian) without reversing the bytes also works:

```
float_out = struct.unpack('<f', bytes.fromhex("35F1AC3D"))[0]
```

Simply perform the operation to each element and voilà.

Per [@Marek Piotrowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5430833/marek-piotrowski)'s suggestion, a bit more information from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters):

> For the 'f', 'd' and 'e' conversion codes, the packed representation
> uses the IEEE 754 binary32, binary64 or binary16 format (for 'f', 'd'
> or 'e' respectively), regardless of the floating-point format used by
> the platform.

Comment: this one works cus python assumes IEEE 754 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters, note 4), could be a worthy addition to the answer imo

Comment: Is it more complex... The first can be obtained easily by the use fromhex and unpack functions. The problem is that after the first 6 elements, the others are not going to decoded into the expected values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @alezmad in this case I would suggest an edit of question to include your data specification and further clarify what you want: do you want the implementation of python to decode the hex string or you want us to showcase decoding the actual data.  I had a typo in my original answer s.t. the format string use the wrong byte order, but my implementaion shows all in your str list can be decoded into numbers between 0 to 1.